# Android ListView not wrapping text

Tags: android, xml, listview

I made a client program on my android and when I receive long messages it doesn't show the whole msg.  I have tried to add `android:orientation="horizontal"` to the XML file but that didn't fix anything.

```
package com.example.marcus.chatclient1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static android.R.layout.list_content;

public class chat extends Activity {
Handler hanGET;
String string = "test";
String name;
EditText msgBox;
Button sButton;
ListView lv;

TextView errorT;
ObjectOutputStream o;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    final Button join = (Button) findViewById(R.id.joinButton);
    final EditText nameT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    msgBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgField);
    sButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    errorT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ChatList);
    msgBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    sButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = nameT.getText().toString();
            join.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            nameT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            msgBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
            final ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
            final ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, ar);
            lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            lv.setAdapter(ad);
            hanGET = new Handler(){
                public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                    ar.add(string);
                    ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
        }
    });
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Message message;
        Socket s;
        try {
            s = new Socket("192.168.0.15", 55555);
            o = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            o.writeObject(name);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        String m = msgBox.getText().toString();
                        o.writeObject(m);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            while(true) {
                try {
                    string = in.readObject().toString();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                message = Message.obtain();
                hanGET.sendMessage(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.marcus.chatclient1.chat">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Join"
    android:id="@+id/joinButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/joinButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/errorText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ChatList"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/joinButton"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_gallery_item"
    tools:listfooter="@layout/activity_chat"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/msgField"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ChatList"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/errorText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/errorText"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/msgField"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/joinButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/joinButton"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView must have the `layout_height` attribute not setted to `wrap_content`. A ListView content height is dynamic, since you don't always have the same number of cells. Thus, you need to match the parent size or have a fixed height.

Comment: how do you make the items in the ListView wrap because i set it to wrap_content but it doesn't wrap it just cuts off some of the text

Comment: because when someone says "Hello how are you doing today" it just shows "Hello how are you"

Comment: Ok so if the listview is ok but only the list items are wrong, you need to show us your list item layout

Comment: `            final ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
            final ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, ar);
            lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            lv.setAdapter(ad);`

Comment: is that what you mean

Comment: use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 one instead